# How to save ArrayList in an Bundle Object

Tags: android

Hi
I need help in finding a way to store

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

in an Bunble object so that i can retrieve  them back in  onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) when an orientation happens .I can find  methods to store simple Arrays in an Bunble,but not an ArrayList like this.

Comment: ganesh, is the answer you got satisfying you? I have the same problem here, I can't understand where that weird `BitmapDrawable` came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you must have a static holder:

```
private static class Holder{
        private List<BitmapDrawable>imageList = new ArrayList<BitmapDrawable>();
    }
```

second, when orientation start, you must return the object you want to retrieve after the orientation:

```
@Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return holder;
    }
```

at last, when you create the 'new' activity must call getLastNonConfigurationInstance(). ANdroid will return your holder with your List.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                holder = (Holder) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

you can find a more extensive explanation here: [Faster Screen Orientation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html).

cheers