# How to save pinpoints and load them back on the map when user reopens app

Tags: android, google-maps, instance, sharedpreferences

I'm having some trouble and head-banging for a while now. The app I'm working on is GPS based together with Google Maps embedded. I can place a pin when tap on any place of the map and what I need is when I reopen the app to see all pins placed already.

I thought about using `SharedPreferences` (method for saving and method for loading back) but since the pins are saved in `ArrayList<Overlay>` I don't really know how to retrieve it (only long, int, string, float, boolean are available).

Is there some other option of doing of this?

Please help.

Comment: i think your array list is of geo points?

Comment: Yeah I guess so.. but how can I retrieve it and load it in onCreate method ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really common problem. Its solved using `Bundles` these questions should provide you will everything you need.  The first explains how to use the bundle to save and load state. The others explain how to save an `ArrayList` to the bundle.

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

[How to save ArrayList in an Bundle Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519820/how-to-save-arraylist-in-an-bundle-object)

[Passing ArrayList Objects through Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084355/passing-arraylist-objects-through-bundle)